# Man command in linux returns "no manual entry for <package_name>"

Tags: linux, command, ubuntu-18.04, manual

When I run the man command in Linux. It returns manual for some packages, but in some case it says

```
no manual entry for <package_name>
```

for-example: man cloud-guest-utils command or man btrfs-tools and some more also.

Is there no manual available for these packages or is there some else issue?

Comment: It could be that the man database needs updating and so run "mandb"

Comment: @RamanSailopal it stills says the same thing no manual entry for <package_name>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that there is simply no manual available for the requested command. You will get the same error if you try `man any-string`.

You may use tab-completion if you are not sure about the man entry name; the tab-completion is usually enabled in the latest distribution.

Comment: I have a list of packages names, for some the man commands runs perfectly but for some it says the what i mentioned in question.

Comment: basically i need to know the configuraton and datafiles path for packages? Is there any other way to get known those. If yes please share. Thanks